# Cannot embed YouTube video

Tags: block-editor, youtube

I know of 3 ways to embed a YouTube video inside Gutenberg

1. Just pasting the Embed code inside an HTML Block
2. Just pasting the video URL
3. Using the YouTube Block

While method #1 seems to work without a problem, I cannot seem to be able to make the others work.

[image]

I keep getting the message "Sorry, this content could not be embedded".

I thought this might be a bug, so I updated to latest version, (5.5.1 at the time I am writing), but the issues still persists. Why could this be?

Comment: Same issue. Did you ever find a solution?